# Gyro sensor :- How to implement motion based action in Android app (using Android Studio)

Tags: android

I am developing an app that implements motion based camera light — when the mobile is in motion, the camera light should get switched on.

Comment: Any code snippet implementing this functionality will be very helpful

Comment: I am using Android studio for development